# How can I send/write two doubles via Bluetooth (nRF8001 Bluefruit LE) in Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

I recently purchased an nRF8001 Bluefruit LE and I am now trying to read/send data with an app. But I am not sure how I can write/send a double value. I want to send two double values at once and to successfully send this, do I have to convert these doubles to a byte array? If so I would very much appreciate how that would look!

This is documentation on how my module works:
https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/nrf-uart-in-detail

Under the headline `Writing data` they give examples on how to send data but as far as I can see (I am a bit new to Arduino code) in their example they only send an int and a string.

I know how to read and set up the module, so it is only the writing/sending doubles that I am struggling with.

These are the two doubles that I wish to send and I control it with:

```
double valueOne;
double valueTwo;
```

The Bluetooth control:

```
Adafruit_BLE_UART BTLEserial = Adafruit_BLE_UART(ADAFRUITBLE_REQ, ADAFRUITBLE_RDY, ADAFRUITBLE_RST);
```

So if I for example do this:

```
BTLEserial.write(valueOne, valueTwo);
```

I get this message: `no matching function for call to 'Adafruit_BLE_UART::write(double&, double&)'`

So do I need to convert these two double values to a byte array and if so how would that look?

Appreciate every help, tips, code! :)

Comment: After the first successful message received, did you see the location refreshed on the serial monitor by the `Serial.println(gps.location.lat(),6);` ?

Comment: I see that once yes and also the `Serial.println(gps.location.lng(),6);` once

Comment: Also the `Serial.println(F("* Connected!"));` once

Comment: Seeing once `Serial.println(F("* Connected!"));` is normal, because the message is sent only when the status change. But are you sure that your `gps.location.isUpdated()` is true ?

Comment: I removed gps.location.isUpdated() in the if-statement but it still stops right when I connect my app to the bluetooth. I also added a `Serial.println("test");` right at the top of the while loop and that stops once i connect the app with the bluetooth as well so there must be something else.

Comment: And what is strange is: If i remove the write/print function. It works and Serial.println(gps.location.lng(),6); keeps getting written out in the log. So it is that last line when I write the data the while loop decides to stop

Comment: When reading the ["nRF UART In Detail"](https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/nrf-uart-in-detail), only 20 bytes could be sent at a time... So, try send a small string in place of sBuffer... Then reduce the size of sBuffer by sending less decimal for your location.

Comment: I kinda need the lat/long decimals to be as exact as possible when i send them. I tried with this code: `String slat = (String)latvalue;
    BTLEserial.print (slat);` but that gave me the same result unfortantly

Comment: I recieve this amount of decimals right now from my lat value 15.728758 which is 8 numbers and the same amount of numbers from my lng value. Should this be a problem?

Comment: Try to send for instance just `"lat,lon"` that very small message... Is it sent periodically ?

Comment: So just `BTLEserial.print("lat,lon");`?

Comment: Same thing :( 
When I connect i get this in the monitor:
* Connected!
0.000000
0.000000

Comment: 0.000000  is the lat, lng that is currently empty and I dont send that, i just write them out in the while loop each time it runs to see if it keeps running after i sent `"lat,lon"`

Comment: Ok I figured out the codeline that makes it work but I am not sure how to solve it without it because I do not want to read current data, i want to send new data. I need this line in order to make it work `String vOut = Serial.readString();`

Comment: Check it out here: https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/nrf-uart-in-detail on the first code example you can find it and how the code works when they write it. If i copy that it works. But if i create my own string and replace that one line i mentioned above `String vOut = Serial.readString();` it does not work.

Comment: I made a new post covering that exact issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link ["Adafruit - nRF UART In Detail"](https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/nrf-uart-in-detail) describes, the function `write(sendbuffer, sendbuffersize);` is waiting for a buffer of `uint8_t` followed by the size of the message.

Here are the step--by-step solution to send the 2 doubles by using that function.

**Step1** - convert the floating-point values into a char string.

> In the Arduino environment, the standard format-specifier `%f or %lf`
>   is not well-managed and the function `dtostrf()` is recommended.

The format is `char *   dtostrf (double __val, signed char __width, unsigned char __prec, char *__s)` where:

- `__val` is the floating-point value to be converted,
- `__s` is the array of char to store the result,
- `__width` is the number of characters to store the result,
- `__prec` is the number of digit

The conversion is:

```
char sValueOne[16], sValueTwo[16];
char sBuffer[33];

strcpy(sBuffer,dtostrf(valueOne, 15, 8, sValueOne));
strcat(sBuffer,",");
strcat(sBuffer,dtostrf(valueTwo, 15, 8, sValueTwo));
```

**Step2** - write the buffer over the `BTLEserial` object.

```
BTLEserial.write((uint8_t *)sBuffer, strlen(sBuffer));
```

> Alternate output solution using `BTLEserial.print()` function.

```
BTLEserial.print(sBuffer);
```

Comment: so should I use a `strcpy`on the sValueOne and a `strcat`on sValueTwo? What does these strcpy and strcpy mean? What type of function is it? Btw, thanks a lot for the answer!! I learned a lot with your example

Comment: Both functions `strcpy()` and `strcat()` are used to copy `char` strings. The first is used to initialize the buffer `char sBuffer[33]` and the second is used to concatenate the extra string to the existing. If `valueOne= 8.89 and valueTwo=9.88`, the first string is `sValueOne =  "8.89000000"` and the second string is `sValueTwo =  "9.98000000"` and the output buffer is `sBuffer = "8.89000000,9.98000000"`.

Comment: How often can I write code? Is it possible to do it each 0.5 second?

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for explaining that! my both doubles cointains 6 numbers after. I send coordinates looking like this:  `double latvalue;
    double lngvalue;

    latvalue = (gps.location.lat(),6);
    lngvalue = (gps.location.lng(),6);`

Comment: The period is highly depending of the real baudrate of your `BTLEserial` device. The conversion is enough fast for two samples per second.

Comment: Alright! Thanks a lot for your help! Appreciate it a lot

Comment: After I write/print with the bluetooth, the `void loop()`stops and it does not keep working/running. Any idea why this is?

Comment: I add a `delay (500);` after the write/print but still the while loop stops after the first "run"

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your source code ?

Comment: Sure one second

Comment: Updated now with source code

Comment: When i connect my phone to the bluetooth device it works once, atleast I think) so becuase I recieve the latvalue + lngvalue when I print out in my serial monitor and also i get  "Connected". But I only recieve this once.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this, but since `Adafruit_BLE_UART` inherits from `Stream`,
which in turn inherits from `Print`, you should be able to

```
BTLEserial.print(valueOne);
BTLEserial.print(",");
BTLEserial.println(valueTwo);
```

Comment: Codes uploads without any trouble! However the while-loop stops with my current code when I use your code as well. It works once (when I connect to the bluetooth with my phone) I edited the post with my source code if you want to check it out.

Comment: If i completely remove write or print and connect to the bluetooth with my app the while loop keeps going but if i add your code or j.piquards code the while loop stops right away when i connect the app with the bluetooth